# How Do I Pipe a String Into a popen() Command in C?

Tags: c, unix, md5, popen

Im working in c (more or less for the first time) for uni, and I need to generate an MD5 from a character array.  The assignment specifies that this must be done by creating a pipe and executing the `md5` command on the system.

I've gotten this far:

```
FILE *in;
extern FILE * popen();
char buff[512];

/* popen creates a pipe so we can read the output
 * of the program we are invoking */
char command[260] = "md5 ";
strcat(command, (char*) file->name);
if (!(in = popen(command, "r"))) {
    printf("ERROR: failed to open pipe\n");
    end(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Now this works perfectly (for another part of the assignment which needs to get the MD5 for a file) but I cant workout how to pipe a string into it.

If I understand correctly, I need to do something like:

```
FILE * file = popen("/bin/cat", "w");
fwrite("hello", 5, file);
pclose(file);
```

Which, I think, would execute cat, and pass "hello" into it through StdIn.  Is this right?

Comment: Did you run that second block code? If you had, you would realize that fwrite takes another parameter, which is the size of an element of your string, so you would probably have tried fwrite("hello",sizeof(char),5,file); and found that this does indeed work.  Whether or not you were supposed to do it this way or by a call to pipe() and then fork() a child, close the ends of the pipe, and send info with a write() and sprintf() is a different idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get a string into the `md5` program, then you need to know what options your `md5` program works with.

- If it takes a string explicitly on the command line, then use that:

  ```
  md5 -s 'string to be hashed'
  ```
- If it takes standard input if no file name is given on the command line, then use:

  ```
  echo 'string to be hashed' | md5
  ```
- If it absolutely insists on a file name and your system supports `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0`, then use:

  ```
  echo 'string to be hashed' | md5 /dev/stdin
  ```
- If none of the above apply, then you will have to create a file on disk, run `md5` on it, and then remove the file afterwards:

  ```
  echo 'string to be hashed' > file.$$; md5 file.$$; rm -f file.$$
  ```

Comment: +1, with the remark that on some systems, the program is called `md5sum`.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment above:

```
FILE* file = popen("/sbin/md5","w");
fwrite("test", sizeof(char), 4, file);
pclose(file);
```

produces an md5 sum

Comment: ok, but how do i get the string BACK - at the moment, your code works, but it prints it to the screen - I need to get it back as a `char*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static char command[256];
snprintf(command, 256, "md5 -qs '%s'", "your string goes here");
FILE* md5 = popen(md5, "r");
static char result[256];
if (fgets(result, 256, md5)) {
     // got it
}
```

If you really want to write it to md5's stdin, and then read from md5's stdout, you're probably going to want to look around for an implementation of popen2(...).  That's not normally in the C library though.

Comment: char* get_string_md5(char* data) {
    static char command[256];
    snprintf(command, 256, "md5 -qs '%s'", data);
    FILE* md5 = popen(md5, "r");
    static char result[256];
    if (fgets(result, 256, md5)) {
        return result;
    }
    printf("ERROR: failed to generate MD5 hash\n");
    end(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Doesnt work :(

Comment: @larsmans: it would work with the /sbin/md5 available on MacOS X 10.6.5.